# Django custom order_by algorithm

Tags: python, django, algorithm, sql-order-by

I want to create a formula for trending posts. I've done this so far:

```
def hot(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    for post in posts:
        likes = int(post.likes)
        views = int(post.blog_view)
        rep = int(post.author.profile.reputation)
        d0 = timezone.now()
        d1 = post.date_posted
        days = (d0 - d1).days
        trending_score = (3/(1+days**(1/3)))*(0.5*views+0.25*rep+2.5*likes)
```

The formula is at trending_score variable, and each time, it returns a number for its trending score. The higher the trending_score, the more trending it is.

Now I want to implement this in django using order_by, or something else:

```
def hot(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    for post in posts:
        likes = int(post.likes)
        views = int(post.blog_view)
        rep = int(post.author.profile.reputation)
        d0 = timezone.now()
        d1 = post.date_posted
        days = (d0 - d1).days
        trending_score = (3/(1+days**(1/3)))*(0.5*views+0.25*rep+2.5*likes)
    context = {
        Post.objects.all().order_by(-trending_score)
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/popularity.html', context)
```

I obviously knew this wasn't going to work, because I put trending_score in the for loop and context is outside of it, so it wasn't going to work. The error was:`Invalid order_by arguments: [-21.75]` But I have no idea how else I can do this. Any help in doing this will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your model?

Comment: Which DB are you using? You should be able to do this with an annotation, calculating the days between 2 dates could be easy or hard depending on the DB though

Answer (score 2):

You can [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) your queryset with values calculated by your formula and then order it based on the annotation. The main thing is to translate your formula to the representation that django ORM understands such that it would convert to a proper SQL statement. Something like this should work:

```
from django.db.models import F, FloatField, DurationField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast, Now, Extract


days = Cast(
    Extract(Cast(Now() - F('date_posted'), DurationField()), 'days'),
    FloatField()
)
views = Cast('views', FloatField())
rep = Cast('post.author.profile.reputation', FloatField())
likes = Cast('likes', FloatField())

Post.objects.all().annotate(
    trending_score=(3./(1+days**(1/3)))*(.5*views+.25*rep+2.5*likes)
).order_by('-trending_score')
```

Comment: There was a comment mentioning that days extraction from duration fails on mySQL. Unfortunately, I can't test the solution with mySQL right now, but extraction does work on postgres. You could check what gets returned from the expression inside the extraction and try an appropriate cast for that type. As an alternative solution, one can have a designated field for `trending_score` on the model and a periodic task which goes over all the objects and updates this field. This is more cumbersome, but allows arbitrary calculations disregarding your DB.

Comment: I fixed this on mysql. Use this:                                                                                      now = timezone.now()
    posted = Cast(now - F('date_posted'), FloatField())
    dates = (now-posted).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix I can think of is, create a new list to store the results. That would allow you to get results ordered on a particular attribute without having to change your models or anything.

```
def hot(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    result = []
    for post in posts:
        likes = int(post.likes)
        views = int(post.blog_view)
        rep = int(post.author.profile.reputation)
        d0 = timezone.now()
        d1 = post.date_posted
        days = (d0 - d1).days
        trending_score = (3/(1+days**(1/3)))*(0.5*views+0.25*rep+2.5*likes)
        result.append((trending_score, post))  #added a tuple of value-object
    context = {
        sorted(result, reverse=True)
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/popularity.html', context)
```

On your HTML page, instead of

```
{% for post in posts %}
```

You can use

```
{% for object in posts %}
post = object[1]
```